# QX1, Manual Shoot mode (M) via API

Tags: camera, sony, sony-camera-api

Very need **M** (Manual) Exposure mode on QX1. I was searching for an answer to the my question, but don't found the exact answer. Can I choose the full manual Exposure mode on QX1 via API?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about *manual* shooting modes on a camera, not programming related.

Comment: I think he's talking about setting the shooting mode via a programmatic API.

Comment: Sorry i mean ExposureMode. I send JSON "getSupportedExposureMode" and QX1 answer me "Intelligent Auto","Aperture","Shutter" but no Manual mode which is very necessary to me.

Comment: Sony PlayMemories software also not present me Manual Exposure mode. May be this option disabled in firmware.

Comment: Maybe you should just try sending "Manual" on `setExposureMode`. The documentation implies that there shouldn't be a problem, so maybe your firmware is out of date?

Comment: it does not work. I get an error:

"error"=>[500, "Set operation failed."]

Comment: May be my firmware is out of date, but I can't find an update on this camera QX1. Please tell me where I can download the new firmware? I was looking only at sony.com support

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't set Manual mode with the current firmware on a QX1 camera.

You are supposed to use the **getAvailableExposureMode** or **getSupportedExposureMode** API methods to retrieve the supported modes (and optionally display them to the user), then use one of only those modes in **setExposureMode**.

But **Manual** mode is not supported by the QX1 camera, so it's not returned by the getSupported/Available methods and that's why the API returns the error to the **setExposureMode** call.

The API is intended to support several SONY cameras with several different features. For each property you have the following API methods:

- **getSupportedProperty** -> Returns the property values supported by the camera.
- **getProperty** -> Returns the actual value for the property
- **setProperty** -> Allows to set a new value for the property
- **getAvailableProperty** -> Returns current value and supported values.

That way, if the app is well coded it will support all the cameras.

So, it's not an API problem but a firmware one. The current firmware for the QX1 does not support Manual mode.

There's not an official firmware update yet :(

https://esupport.sony.com/US/p/model-home.pl?mdl=ILCEQX1&LOC=3#/downloadTab

Comment: Thanks for this. I think this shows that currently the QX1 is a mostly useless toy. Without Manual Mode there is no way to take useful sky pictures. I have cancelled my order.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this found here : https://github.com/erik-smit/sony-camera-api/blob/master/actEnableMethods.sh

other references to this hack here: http://chdk.setepontos.com/index.php?topic=10736.10
i could not get it to work but if it can help in your research in any way

```
public String getDG() throws IOException {
    String service = "accessControl";
    try {
        JSONObject paramsMethods =
                new JSONObject().put("developerName","");
        paramsMethods.put("sg","");
        paramsMethods.put("methods","");
       paramsMethods.put("developerID","");

        JSONObject requestJson =
                new JSONObject().put("method", "actEnableMethods") //
                        .put("params", new JSONArray().put(paramsMethods)) //
                        .put("id", id()).put("version", "1.0");

        String url = findActionListUrl(service) + "/" + service;

        log("Request:  " + requestJson.toString());
        String responseJson = SimpleHttpClient.httpPost(url, requestJson.toString());
        log("Response: " + responseJson);
        JSONArray resultsObj = new JSONObject(responseJson).getJSONArray("result");

        String dg = null;
        JSONObject dgobj = resultsObj.getJSONObject(0);
        dg = dgobj.getString("dg");


        return dg;

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        throw new IOException(e);
    }

}

public String getSG(String dg){
    MessageDigest md;
    String keydg = "90adc8515a40558968fe8318b5b023fdd48d3828a2dda8905f3b93a3cd8e58dc" + dg;
    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.update(keydg.getBytes());
        String SG = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));

        return SG;
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
    return null;
}

public JSONObject actEnableMethods() throws IOException {
    String DG = getDG();
    String SG = getSG(DG);
    String service = "accessControl";
    try {
    JSONObject paramsMethods =
    new JSONObject().put("developerName","Sony Corporation");
    paramsMethods.put("sg",SG);
    paramsMethods.put("methods","camera/setFlashMode:camera/getFlashMode:camera/getSupportedFlashMode:camera/getAvailableFlashMode:camera/setExposureCompensation:camera/getExposureCompensation:camera/getSupportedExposureCompensation:camera/getAvailableExposureCompensation:camera/setSteadyMode:camera/getSteadyMode:camera/getSupportedSteadyMode:camera/getAvailableSteadyMode:camera/setViewAngle:camera/getViewAngle:camera/getSupportedViewAngle:camera/getAvailableViewAngle:camera/setMovieQuality:camera/getMovieQuality:camera/getSupportedMovieQuality:camera/getAvailableMovieQuality:camera/setFocusMode:camera/getFocusMode:camera/getSupportedFocusMode:camera/getAvailableFocusMode:camera/setStillSize:camera/getStillSize:camera/getSupportedStillSize:camera/getAvailableStillSize:camera/setBeepMode:camera/getBeepMode:camera/getSupportedBeepMode:camera/getAvailableBeepMode:camera/setCameraFunction:camera/getCameraFunction:camera/getSupportedCameraFunction:camera/getAvailableCameraFunction:camera/setLiveviewSize:camera/getLiveviewSize:camera/getSupportedLiveviewSize:camera/getAvailableLiveviewSize:camera/setTouchAFPosition:camera/getTouchAFPosition:camera/cancelTouchAFPosition:camera/setFNumber:camera/getFNumber:camera/getSupportedFNumber:camera/getAvailableFNumber:camera/setShutterSpeed:camera/getShutterSpeed:camera/getSupportedShutterSpeed:camera/getAvailableShutterSpeed:camera/setIsoSpeedRate:camera/getIsoSpeedRate:camera/getSupportedIsoSpeedRate:camera/getAvailableIsoSpeedRate:camera/setExposureMode:camera/getExposureMode:camera/getSupportedExposureMode:camera/getAvailableExposureMode:camera/setWhiteBalance:camera/getWhiteBalance:camera/getSupportedWhiteBalance:camera/getAvailableWhiteBalance:camera/setProgramShift:camera/getSupportedProgramShift:camera/getStorageInformation:camera/startLiveviewWithSize:camera/startIntervalStillRec:camera/stopIntervalStillRec:camera/actFormatStorage:system/setCurrentTime");
    paramsMethods.put("developerID","7DED695E-75AC-4ea9-8A85-E5F8CA0AF2F3");

        JSONObject requestJson =
                new JSONObject().put("method", "actEnableMethods") //
                        .put("params", new JSONArray().put(paramsMethods)) //
                        .put("id", id()).put("version", "1.0");
        String url = findActionListUrl(service) + "/" + service;

        log("Request:  " + requestJson.toString());
        String responseJson = SimpleHttpClient.httpPost(url, requestJson.toString());
        log("Response: " + responseJson);
        return new JSONObject(responseJson);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        throw new IOException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can. Per the table [here](https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/), you can set the Exposure Mode on the QX1. You can use the `setExposureMode` API method with something like the following JSON:

```
{
    "method": "setExposureMode",
    "params": ["Manual"],
    "id": 1,
    "version": "1.0"
}
```

Source:

API Reference downloaded from https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/get-started/

Comment: I tried setExposureMode to "Manual" it does not work. After send JSON setExposureMode 

I get an error:

"error"=>[500, "Set operation failed."]

Don't set the manual exposure mode on ILCE-QX1 even through the API too.

I hope to fix it in the firmware update. Really need this mode.