# Format the SD Card in a Sony ILCE-QX1 camera via SDK

Tags: sdk, camera, sony, sony-camera-api

I am trying to format the SD card in a Sony ILCE-QX1 camera.  The SDK documentation does not provide a command to do this.  I know it is possible because it can be done from the Sony PlayMemories application on iOS or Android.  Does anyone know the command to do this?

Comment: By dumping all commands from SDK I see a actFormatStorage in the camera group.  I have tried this command with guesses for param etc without success.  Anyone done this?

Comment: By looking at getEvent data I know it is expecting a string for the param, just not sure what it is looking for.  Maybe the storagecard id?

Comment: wondering if anyone from Sony monitors this forum to provide answers...

Comment: From this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27490892/qx1-manual-shoot-mode-m-via-api, found that need to send actEnableMethods to turn on the actFormatStorage command.  That requires a handshake of a "dg" value to create an "sg" value to send in a second actEnableMethods. I am unable to get that to work using the code provided I get an {"id":1,"error":[5,"illegal request"]} response.  Any ideas?  I think it must be in the dg to sg hashing.